# Saving command into variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

I've question about this variables.How can I store **result of a command** into a variable? For example: saving drive serial into location variable.
thanks.
E.g:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET location=vol
ECHO We're working with %location%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('your command and parameters') do set "var=%%x"
```

where the `'single quotes'` are required around the command from which you wish to save output.

---

Edit - now we know which command.

Comment - one variable can contain up to ~8,000 characters.

Here's a routine that will set the values in $1...$whatever and the entire set in $all with each field enclosed in angle-brackets.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "$all="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
  'systeminfo 2^>nul^|findstr /n /r "$"'
  ) DO (
 SET "$%%a=%%b"
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%c IN ("%%b") DO CALL SET "$all=%%$all%%<%%c>"
 SET /a max=%%a
)

SET $
pause
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%max%) DO CALL ECHO %%$%%z%%

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you...please see my batch file contents:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('systeminfo') do set "var=%%x"

command_line.exe %var%
```

only last line of 'systeminfo' saved in var variable and it is:
"data execution perevention available: yes"

I want to store all contetnt of systeminfo into variable!